# Variable scope. Use a closure?

Tags: javascript, ajax, scope, closures

I'm trying to grab all the URLs of my Facebook photos.
I first load the "albums" array with the album id's.
Then I loop through the albums and load the "pictures" array with the photos URLs. 
(I see this in Chrome's JS debugger).

But when the code gets to the last statement ("return pictures"), "pictures" is empty.

How should I fix this? 
I sense that I should use a closure, but not entirely sure how to best do that. 
Thanks.

```
function getMyPhotos() {

        FB.api('/me/albums', function(response) {
            var data = response.data;
            var albums = [];
            var link;
            var pictures = [];


            // get selected albums id's
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                if ((value.name == 'Wall Photos')) { 
                        albums.push(value.id);
                }
            });
            console.log('albums');
            console.log(albums);

            // get the photos from those albums
            $.each(albums, function(key, value) {
                FB.api('/' + value + '/photos', function(resp) {
                     $.each(resp.data, function(k, val) {      
                            link = val.images[3].source;
                            pictures.push(link);
                     });
                });
            });

            console.log('pictures');
            console.log(pictures);
            return pictures;

        });
    }
```

Comment: The problem isn't variable scope, it's that the ajax calls are asynchronous (as well they should be). This question has been asked in one form or another time and time again, every day since the dawn of SO. The sort answer is that you can't/shouldn't `return` anything from the outer function. Use a callback inside of the `FB.api` callback if you have further code that depends on `pictures`.

Comment: I need to return an array with all the photos across all the albums. How would I do this inside the callback within the 2nd nested FB.api call? I have to wait until the entire "pictures" array is filled before I return it.

Comment: @JMan You don't return a value inside the callback, because there is no-one left to return it to (remember, the call to getMyPhotos already exited).  You use the callback to notify whoever is intersted with "hey, here's the data you requested"

Comment: Like I said: **you cannot `return` the `pictures` array.** If there is code that depends on it being filled, it needs to be executed in the `FB.api` callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're thinking about your problem procedurally.  However, this logic fails anytime you work with asynchronous requests.  I expect what you originally tried to do looked something like this:

```
var pictures = getMyPhotos();
for (var i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++) {
    // do something with each picture
}
```

But, that doesn't work since the value of 'pictures' is actually undefined (which is the default return type of any function without an actual return defined -- which is what your getMyPhotos does)

Instead, you want to do something like this:

```
function getMyPhotos(callback) {
    FB.api('/me/albums', function (response) {
        // process respose data to get a list of pictures, as you have already 
        // shown in your example

        // instead of 'returning' pictures, 
        // we just call the method that should handle the result
        callback(pictures);
    });
}

// This is the function that actually does the work with your pictures
function oncePhotosReceived(pictures){
    for (var i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++) {
      // do something with each picture
    }
};

// Request the picture data, and give it oncePhotosReceived as a callback.
// This basically lets you say 'hey, once I get my data back, call this function'
getMyPhotos(oncePhotosReceived);
```

I highly recommend you scrounge around SO for more questions/answers about AJAX callbacks and asynchronous JavaScript programming.

EDIT:

If you want to keep the result of the FB api call handy for other code to use, you can set the return value onto a 'global' variable in the window:

```
function getMyPhotos(callback) {
    FB.api('/me/albums', function (response) {
        // process respose data to get a list of pictures, as you have already 
        // shown in your example

        // instead of 'returning' pictures, 
        // we just call the method that should handle the result
        window.pictures = pictures;
    });
}
```

You can now use the global variable 'pictures' (or, explicitly using window.pictures) anywhere you want. The catch, of course, being that you have to call getMyPhotos first, and wait for the response to complete before they are available.  No need for localStorage.

Comment: Thanks, Matt, I understand.  But the rest of my code will occasionally need access to the photos, so all of it needs to be nested inside getMyPhotos()? Is there a way out of this nesting messiness? I'm thinking about writing the photo links to HTML5 localStorage so that other code can reference it later.

Comment: @JMan updated my answer.  A lot of people avoid putting data in the global namespace, but I would say at your stage of JS development it is an acceptable compromise (not to mention easier than localStorage).  The one benefit localStorage would give is you wouldn't have to make the getMyPhotos call each time the page loaded, instead grab it from localStorage

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, asynchronous code is like Hotel California - you can check any time you like *but you can never leave*.

Have you noticed how the `FB.api` does not return a value

```
//This is NOT how it works:
var result = FB.api('me/albums')
```

but instead receives a continuation function and passes its results on to it?

```
FB.api('me/albums', function(result){
```

Turns out you need to have a similar arrangement for your getMyPhotos function:

```
function getMyPhotos(onPhotos){
    //fetches the photos and calls onPhotos with the 
    // result when done

    FB.api('my/pictures', function(response){

        var pictures = //yada yada

        onPhotos(pictures);
    });
}
```

---

Of course, the continuation-passing style is contagious so you now need to call

```
getMyPhotos(function(pictures){
```

instead of

```
var pictures = getMyPhotos();
```